# Is it possible to use owl carousel with react without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am trying to figure it out if I can use [React Owl Carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-owl-carousel) without using jQuery as it mess up with React ecosystem.

The tutorial said that you need to add these codes webpack:

```
// ...
plugins: [
    // other plugins,
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    }),
],
//...
```

Which actually traversing the dom before you can even proceed with the next steps.

Wondering if there's a workaround here to avoid jQuery? or are there any alternative that I can use that don't use jQuery?

PS. I like the simplicity of owl carousel but there is a trade off with using jQuery in React